# wsgi.py cannot be loaded as Python module Error / No module named 'django.core'

Tags: django, apache, centos, wsgi, django-wsgi

I have configured Django 2.1.15 on Centos 7 with Apache 2.4.6-93., mod_wsgi, Virtualenv and Postgres.

And here is my apache conf file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/

        Alias /static /var/www/myapp/static
        <Directory /var/www/myapp/static>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>


        ErrorLog /var/www/myapp/logs/apis_error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/myapp/logs/apis_access.log combined
        LogLevel info
        WSGIPassAuthorization On
        WSGIDaemonProcess myapp  python-path=/var/www/myapp:/var/www/myapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup myapp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py
        <Directory /var/www/myapp/myapp/myapp>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The Apache log error:

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 4829]  mod_wsgi (pid=4829, process='myapp', application=''): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error] [pid 4829]  mod_wsgi (pid=4829): Target WSGI script '/var/www/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[wsgi:error] [pid 4829]  mod_wsgi (pid=4829): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error] [pid 4829]  Traceback (most recent call last):
[wsgi:error] [pid 4829]    File "/var/www/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[wsgi:error] [pid 4829]      from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[wsgi:error] [pid 4829]  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core'
[wsgi:info]  [pid 4829] mod_wsgi (pid=4829, process='myapp', application=''): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error] [pid 4829] mod_wsgi (pid=4829): Target WSGI script '/var/www/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[wsgi:error] [pid 4829]  mod_wsgi (pid=4829): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error] [pid 4829]  Traceback (most recent call last):
[wsgi:error] [pid 4829]    File "/var/www/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[wsgi:error] [pid 4829]      from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[wsgi:error] [pid 4829]  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core'
```

Any idea what might be going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to make some changes to `vhost` conf like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName myapp.local  # HERE: "ServerName" is missing

    DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp  # HERE: point to the root folder of your app
    
    Alias /static /var/www/myapp/static
    <Directory /var/www/myapp/static>
        # Options FollowSymLinks
        # Order allow,deny
        # Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp  python-path=/var/www/myapp:/var/www/myapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup myapp
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py
    <Directory /var/www/myapp/myapp>  # HERE: give the right location of "wsgi.py"
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    LogLevel info
    ErrorLog /var/www/myapp/logs/apis_error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/myapp/logs/apis_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks @cizaro, but this seems not the issue. I have restart the project and this issue comes in each time I start using Postgres db, so my guess is that it is related to psycopg2 ..